# Connect to HTTPS through untrusted proxy

Tags: tls, network, web-browser, proxy

As far as I know, and please correct me if I'm wrong, I can connect to an https site (assuming the whole page is https) while using a free proxy server I find on the web (and entered into Firefox's proxy settings), *completely* securely. The only thing the proxy will know is the domain I'm connecting to. Nothing else. It won't know the passwords I'm typing, nor even the exact page or query string following the domain.

Is there ANYTHING that I need to do to ensure that is the case, or is that automatic by the nature of https?

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts...

1. Make sure that the site you got is the site you requested. (and
   *hope* the characters in the url *are* the same, not just [*look* the same](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDN_homograph_attack).)
2. Keep an eye out for the site reverting to http at some point, leaking information.

These are just some ideas to help those who are not security oriented. I'm still interested in an expert's answer, of course.